# How to use drag behavior from d3js with leapjs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag, leap-motion

I am trying to control a parallel-coordinates-chart ([parcoords.js from D3js framework](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/iris-parallel.html)) with my leap motion controller.

So at the parcoords.js file is a drag function which uses the standard d3js drag behavior, which supports touch and mouse, described here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-drag

But I try to realize a grad-gesture by the leap motion to drag the axis around individually. Solving this I need to map the leap-coordinates to control the mouse via javascript. Another solution might be to call the reorder-able function, when a grab is detected by my javascript. But I do not know how to use the leap-finger coordinates to work with d3js drag behavior.

I hope anyone have an idea to solve this Problem.

A demo of the d3js parallel coordinates can be found here: http://3developers.de/parcoords/

There is also a red square to show you leap finger position.

Yours Lucas

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you would need to define what a "drag gesture" is. Here are some options:

- Any finger ("pointable") movement. So as soon as the controller detects a finger, the dragging starts and is defined by the movement of the finger. The drag stops when the finger leaves the area where it can be detected by the controller.
- A [gesture](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/devguide/Leap_Gestures.html#id19) starts the drag. This could be for example a "tapping screen" gesture. The drag then follows the movement of the respective finger and stops when the gesture is repeated.

You can further restrict when dragging starts by requiring the finger to be immediately above the respective element.

In any case, D3 doesn't offer direct support for leap motions, so you would have to manually trigger the events for dragstart, drag and dragend.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have the problem that with the leap data I get, I can create a virtual pointer like a mouse but I can not click on anything or make a pressed mouse an drag such an axis in my visualization. So I have no idea how to transform my leap position to as example a singe touch or drag event. Maybe my concern is now a bit clearer.

Comment: There's not really a concept of a click. To do a "click", you could use one of the options I've outlined.

Comment: I´ve now found this answer from you and I think it´s equal to this what I´d like to have. But I cant see the possibility to pass my 2D Array of LeapPointer coordinates to the drag function of my parallel coordinates from d3.js. Here is the post I´ve mentioned in the comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798672/is-it-possible-to-use-non-mouse-non-touch-events-to-interact-with-a-d3-js-graph

Comment: You'll need to construct D3 events with those coordinates and call the event handler on them. This is messy, but as I've said, D3 doesn't offer direct support for this kind of interaction.